# Resetting JQuery validate within a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to clear the contents of a form in a JQuery Dialog which uses JQuery validate.

It's barking on my assignment of (dialog).validate(); "dialog.validate is not a function"

```
// dialog is an ID of a dialog, in this case, "#myDialog" is passed in
function reset(dialog){
    var validator = (dialog).validate();
    validator.resetForm();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Dialog` is a string, not a DOM element. You're calling `validate` on a string. It seems you've forgotten the `$`. This:

```
var validator = (dialog).validate();
```

Should be this:

```
var validator = $(dialog).validate();
```

Comment: Hah, I feel stupid - thanks for pointing that out :) - dumb mistake.

Comment: sry.. I didn't quite get it .. the id begins with "#"?

Comment: @radashk - Yes, but he specifically says "in this case, "#myDialog" is passed in" Notice the "#"